# Laravel Query Builder - Query on Date Not Working

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a query like this in Laravel Query Builder-

```
    $baseQuery  =   DB::table(  'project');
    //$startDate="2015-09-02" - This format
    //$endtDate="2014-08-02" - This format
    if(!empty($startDate))
        $baseQuery  =   $baseQuery->where('project.completion_date', '>', $startDate);
    if(!empty($endData))
        $baseQuery  =   $baseQuery->where('project.completion_date', '<', $endData);
```

Comment: What does not work? And is the `if(!empty($endData))` correct? (Should not be `if(!empty($endDate))` or your `$endtDate`?)

Comment: Indeed, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$startDate = empty($startDate) ? '1970-01-01' : $startDate;
$endDate = empty($endDate) ? '2038-01-01' : $endDate;

DB::table('project')
    ->whereBetween('completion_date', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->get();
```

Comment: No, it is not because as u see any data can be empty